# Symfony Messenger Performance

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, symfony-messenger

I have a performance problem running some RabbitMQ queues on both my local machine and on the production server.

At first I thought that it was the consumer which connects to DB and runs some queries, but now I created a new empty message consumer, which does nothing:

```
class TestRabbitMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __invoke(TestRabbitDataMessage $message)
    {
    }
}
```

And message class is:

```
class TestRabbitDataMessage
{
    private $test;

    public function __construct(string $test)
    {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    public function getTest(): string
    {
        return $this->test;
    }
}
```

Now then I run the consumer and open the RabbitMQ dashboard I see that only 50 messages per second is consumed. Keeping in mind that consumer does nothing it looks like something is wrong with the configuration.

messenger.yaml:

```
messenger:
    failure_transport: failed
    serializer:
        symfony_serializer:
            format: json
    transports:
        test_rabbit:
            dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN_TEST_RABBIT)%'
            options:
                verify: false
                queues:
                    test_rabbit:
                        arguments:
                            x-queue-type: 'quorum'
                retry_strategy:
                    max_retries: 3
                    delay: 300000
                    multiplier: 2
                    max_delay: 0
```

Message insert is running like 1000 messages per second, so that is fine, but there is something wrong with the consumer. Messages consumer is running with debug mode disabled. Any ideas?

Command to start the consumer local:

`php bin/console messenger:consume test_rabbit -vvv`

Production uses pretty much the same configs, except the commands is being run by supervisor so multiple consumers runs at the same time.

Also I tried the `auto_setup: false` parameter which almost doubled my consumer speed, which is now at around 100 per second. But it still looks like it's crazy slow for a queue which does nothing.

Comment: What command do you useto consume your messages ?  What is the configuration on the production server ?

Comment: The problem can come from many things, this can be a network latency, and not a configuration issue. I'll recommend you to debug with a profiling tool like blackfire to see where the time goes